# Shared folder access from Windows 10 in virtual box

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have Win10 guest OS inside virtual box.
I have connected host's `E:` drive as shared folder in guest OS as `E:`
[Shared folder settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tV6a7.png)
When I try to create file there by following code

```
  const string logFilename = "C:\\TelerikLog\\results{0}.txt";
  var path = string.Format(logFilename, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));

  try
  {
    var file = new StreamWriter(path, true);
    file.WriteLine(msg);
    file.Close();
  }
  catch (DirectoryNotFoundException e)
  {
    throw new DirectoryNotFoundException(e.Message);
  }
```

I've got a exception

```
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 
Could not find a part of the path 'E:\TelerikLog\results20160804.txt'.
```

This code successfully works on Windows 7 guest with the same settings but unable to work after upgrade to Win10.

Also I'm able to create .txt file in this folder via cmd

```
C:\Users\algot>copy nul > E:\TelerikLog\results20160804_test.txt
C:\Users\algot>dir E:\TelerikLog\*test.txt
 Volume in drive E is VBOX_E
 Volume Serial Number is A219-E60D
 Directory of E:\TelerikLog
 08/04/2016  03:11 PM                27 results20160804_test.txt
               1 File(s)             27 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  351,134,318,592 bytes free
```

What can cause it?

Comment: So you've done (in the guest): `net use E: \\<your_vbox_hostname>\E` ?

Comment: No, but I can see shared folder as E: drive in my guest
Is it mandatory?

Comment: @Big Chris  I've just run `net use` without parameters and got    `Status       Local     Remote                    Network
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             E:        \\vboxsrv\E               VirtualBox Shared Folders
The command completed successfully.`

Comment: Sorry, i mis-read your second half to your question.. i thought your command prompt didn't work. Sorry. Hmm